# Use Xcode project in another project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I need to use some controllers from one of my project to another so i am trying to add that Xcode project to my project but i am not sure how can access those controller in my new project.

Here is an example.

```
OLDProject.XcodeProj
- XXXXXController.h
- XXXXXController.m

NewProject.XcodeProj
I am adding OLDProject.XcodeProj to newProject.
now i needs to import XXXXXController.h file in this project
```

I want to do without creating static library.

Answer (score 3):

In XCode, you can create a WorkSpace that contains your projects. Then from one project, you can call to a class of another project.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html

ANd how to create workspace & add existing projects into your workspace:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/Creating_a_Workspace.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009934-CH9-SW1

Comment: I did it already but i am not able to import any controller from OLDProject

Comment: Excuse-me, in my memory, I had 1 main project & severals Library Project. I think that if you have 2 application project, this does not work. You have to import your self your viewcontroller from OLDProject to NEWProject (just add link, do not copy). Then update your "Search Header Paths" setting in your NEWProject Build Setting